# Swing the iPhone like a golf club

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiaccelerometer

I understand that I have to use the UIAccelerometer to detect which angles that will exist in a regular golf swing.

The best equivalent that came to my mind is that I want to use the iPhone just like the Nintento Wii control.

Is it possible to swing the iPhone like a golf club and be able to decide:

- Wheather it's a *roughly* accurate swing (if it's more like a tennis swing = throw error)
- Perhaps store the angles the iphone registers on the "back swing". If I store five values each x second on the "back swing" and then check if these values are *roughly* equal to the "front swing".
- I also need to decide how hard the swing is, perhaps if I can check this a moment before the iphone reaches the default position (start position before starting the swing movement). I know that I can't calculate the speed between two positions with UIAccelerometer, but maybe I can solve this in some other way?

---

### Answer from Apple Review Team on this question

> Thank you for contacting the App
>   Review team. Apple is not able to
>   provide pre-approval to developers for
>   proposed application submissions or to
>   review and comment on application
>   concepts, including business models.
>   **That said, the concept does not
>   violate the guidelines**; however, the
>   app will need to be evaluated to
>   ensure the implementation is in
>   compliance.

Personally I think an app like this would be approved, but an app where you is supposed to throw you device as near as possible to a location should be disapproved. This is how I interpret this.

Anyway, I've learned that my question, which was if the swing was possible, is absolutely doable with the usage of the Accelerometer with a High pass fitler and a Low pass filter.

**Have in consideration:** If you are about to develop an app with the same concept, don't get angry if it gets rejected.

Comment: Some people are going to smash their iPhone when this app is released :)

Comment: I just want to know how to develop this, it's for my own winning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reasonable chance that Apple won't let an app like this into the app store. Read the human interface guidlines: they say to not encourage the user to do anything which might cause them to damage their device. And with doing a golf swing, I can imagine somebody somewhere letting go of their iPhone and then kablooie...

Comment: I understand that, but my intention isn't to upload this app to the App Store. I'm curious of how to solve this question.